# Sending mails form grails does not work

Tags: email, grails, intellij-idea, plugins

I have a problem with sending mails from grails. Add an exception to port 587, but nothing helped. Still an error occur:

Connection refused: connect. Stacktrace follows:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:432)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder.sendMessage(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:131)
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:55)
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:59)
    at grailsproject.UserController.save(UserController.groovy:31)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2118)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:712)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:501)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:421)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:331)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2084)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

application.yml

```
mail:
         host: "smtp.gmail.com"
         port: 465
         username: "***@gmail.com"
         password: "***"
         props:
             mail.smtp.auth: "true"
             mail.smtp.socketFactory.port: "465"
             mail.smtp.socketFactory.class: "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
             mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback: "true"
```

build.gradle

```
runtime "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC4"
```

I have tried also with:
runtime "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0"
runtime "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC6"
and also does not work.

UserController.groovy

```
package grailsproject
class UserController {

    def mailService

    def form() {
    }

    def save() {

        def user = new Userr(params)
        user.validate()
        if(user.hasErrors())
        {
            user.errors.allErrors.each {
                println it
            }
            render (view:"/registrationForm/registrationForm", model: [user: user]);
        }else
        {
            user.save(flush: true)
            render(view: "user", model: [user: user]);
        }

        mailService.sendMail{
            to "***@gmail.com"
            from "***@gmail.com"
            subject "This is a test mail"
            body "Hello, This is a test mail, how are you?"
        }

    }


}
```

I do not have idea, what else should I check...
I am also wondering why it try to connect localhost when I gave there gmail host?

Comment: I'd guess the config must be under the `grails`-root.

Comment: Read docs, please. @cfrick is right, you need to move config under grails.
So it must be grails { mail {} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application.yml should be

```
grails:
     mail:
          host: "smtp.gmail.com"                                               
          port: 465                                                            
          username: "your_mail@gmail.com"                                       
          password: "Your_password"                                                 
          props:
              mail.smtp.auth: "true"                                           
              mail.smtp.socketFactory.port: "465"                              
              mail.smtp.socketFactory.class: "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
              mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback: "false"
```

build.gradle wiil be

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC6"
```

UserController.groovy should be

```
package grailsproject

class UserController {

    def index() { }

    def send() {
        def multipartFile = request.getFile('attachment')

        sendMail {
            multipart true
            to params.address
            subject params.subject
            html params.body
            if(multipartFile && !multipartFile.empty) {
                File tmpFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
                multipartFile.transferTo(tmpFile);
                attach tmpFile
            }
        }
        flash.message = "Email Sent Successfully"
        redirect action:"index"
    }
}
```